# Definitions of proper maps

Tags: general-topology, compactness

As far as I know, there several definitions of a proper map.

1. A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is proper if it is continuous and for any space $Z$, the product $f\times \operatorname{id_Z}\colon X\times Z\to Y\times Z$ is closed.
2. A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is proper if it is continuous, closed, and preimages of points in $Y$ are compact.
3. A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is proper if it is closed, continuous, and preimages of compact sets are compact.
4. The same as 3., only not necessarily closed.
5. The same as 4., only not necessarily continuous.

Bourbaki shows that the first two are equivalent (and that they are equivalent to two other definitions using filters). The last three are clearly progressively weaker.

Frankly, I'm quite confused now. So the question is: what are the implications between those properties (maybe under some additional assumptions about the spaces), and what other definitions of properness of a map may I come across in the future (and, obviously, how do those relate to the ones I have listed above). If scoured the internet for some time, but have not found any source which would clear up the confusion - I have only stumbled upon some partial results and vague remarks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure now that 2. and 3. are equivalent. Also, the following MO post is sort of relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/a/56490

Comment: Bourbaki answers almost all of your question. (All references are about Topologie Générale I §10.) By Proposition 6, 1. implies 3. (when compact means quasi-compact), and clearly 3. implies 2., which is equivalent to 1. by Théorème 1. As you noted, 3. implies 4. and by Proposition 7, the converse holds as soon as $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ is locally compact. By Exercise 9) b), if $X$ is regular and $Y$ is locally compact, then 5. implies 4.
I don't know any examples to show that the extra-assumptions can't be dropped, though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "what other definitions of properness of a map may I come across in the future":  In my opinion the most intuitive definition of **properness** goes as follows:

Take a sequence $(x_k)_k$ in a space $X$.  We say that $(x_k)_k$ **escapes to infinity** if every compact subset $K\subset X$ only contains a *finite* number of points $x_k$.

A continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$ between topological spaces is **proper** if the image of any sequence $(x_k)_k \subset X$ escaping to infinity in $X$ is a sequence $\bigl(f(x_k)\bigr)_k \subset Y$ that escapes to infinity in $Y$.

This definition is equivalent to the standard one for reasonable spaces (wikipedia says for metric spaces), but I find it much clearer.